# How do you configure desktop for a static IP address?

Tags: networking, network-manager

By default Ubuntu uses DHCP and Gnome NetworkManger to configure interfaces. This is not optimal in many cases.

How to configure a desktop machine for a static IP address that applies to all users?

**Additional background**: For 99.9% of users a static DHCP entry is probably the easiest solution, however I have found a conflict with `mythtv-background` process and any changes to the eth0 interface. If the interface is brought up/down after mythtv is running, it hangs the process (which also broke system suspend). So my questions really needs a **static** IP address, where the interface is brought up with a known IP, and stays up permanently.

Comment: As a side note, you can use DHCP reservation in your router, which will reserve the IP for your computer by identifying it by the NIC's MAC address, and this will literally behave as if a Static IP is set.

Comment: thanks good tip for someone just looking for the consistent IP address

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right click nm, choose *Edit connections...* find your interface, click *Edit...*, click *IPv4 Settings*, choose *Manual* and configure your interface.

An alternative would be to edit */etc/network/interfaces*. an example configuration would be:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

then run

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Keep in mind that this will deactivate nm for this interface and you will have to delete (or uncomment) the entries to activate nm again.

Edit (see Casey's post):
You also have to set a DNS after editing /etc/network/interfaces:

> Set one or more desired nameserver in
>   /etc/resolv.conf:
>
> nameserver 192.168.1.1

Comment: after 'networking restart', only lo interface comes up

Comment: The interface name (`eth0` in sBlatt's example) might be different on your PC: `eth0` is the usual name for the first _wired_ ethernet interface; there is no standard for naming wireless interfaces.  The command `ip link show` will display a list of network interfaces, along with their relevant parameters.

Comment: Alternatively, after right clicking on network manager and choosing "Edit Connections", choose whether it will be wired or wireless, then click "Add".  After adding the static IP as desired, close all the dialogs then left-click on the network manager icon.  You'll now have the option of "Auto Eth0" which is DHCP, and the connection you added manually.  You can do this multiple times, building up a list of different static IP addresses for each location or circumstance you might find yourself in.

Comment: @Riccardo, yes my interface is eth0. Like I said, only making the changes in interfaces is not a working solution for me

Comment: @Scain, do changes in network manager apply to all users? My problem was that switching users would bring the interface down and back up. That is not really static.

Comment: How do you tell it only brings up lo? Did you try "sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart" ? I just tested these instructions, worked as expected...

Comment: @Casey, this isn't an area I've spent much time in, but I believe there's an option there for "Apply for all users".  I think this is mostly for WIFI, since an SSID key is required for connection, so if you want to share that WIFI connection across all users or guests, then you'd need to chose that option.  Doing so moves the SSID key from your gnome-keyring to somewhere shared, but actually /where/ is a bit of a mystery!

Answer (score 5):

Update `/etc/networking/interfaces`to set the static address:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Set one or more desired nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

You must prevent *gnome-network-manager* from attempting to hijack the `eth0` connection:

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Assign static IP address by restarting the networking sub-system:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d networking restart
```

Comment: **Do not remove network-manager!** You run a risk of ending up with no internet connection at all, if you make some mistakes in setting up the static IP (and you are not able to correct them).

Comment: You can tell NetworkManager not to automatically bring an interface up (right-click -> _Edit connections..._ -> select one -> _Edit..._ -> click on the _Connect automatically_ checkbox); this way you can still have network manager installed and manually activate interfaces via `ifup`/`ifdown`

Comment: Besides, my comment was there to alert users with the same problem that removing network-manager is a risky route to take.  You are evidently able to manage your network connection and troubleshoot problems; other readers of this question might not...

Comment: Shouldn't `/etc/networking/interfaces` be `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a little router logged into it, (something like http://192.168.1.1 from you browser), record current DNS server addresses. Reserver one more IP address from DHCP, (something like 192.168.1.200-192.168.1.210), or disable DHCP all together.

From Ubuntu menu:
System --> Preferences --> Network Connections --> Auto eth0 --> edit --> IPV4 Settings --> Change it to Manual --> add ip, (something like 192.168.1.200 what you reservered above), netmask 255.255.255.0,, and router inside address for default route, (something like 192.168.1.1 what you used to log into it)  --> Enter the DNS server addresses you recorded at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I updated my question a little to explain why this solution will not work for me. I need the interface to stay up permanently.

Comment: It will always come up @ this address when you boot, (in this example 192.168.0.200), And stay up  permanently.  Your router is not setting it anymore via DHCP.  It is hard coded into the computer.

Answer (score 1):

1) check which interface should be configed, assume the interface you want to change is `eth0` in this case:

```
$ ip addr
```

2) open and edit `/etc/network/interface`:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/network/interface
```

3) add the following lines to the file `/etc/network/interface`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.22
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

3) restart your interface with command `ifdown` and `ifup`:

```
$ sudo ifdown --force eth0
$ sudo ifup --force eth0
```

PS: use `$ sudo systemctl restart networking` or `$ sudo ifup eth0`  may do not working when other networking tools are being used, please also check [Can't ifdown eth0 (main interface)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/cant-ifdown-eth0-main-interface)