# Configuring a persistent static IP address 

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you configure desktop for a static IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7079/how-do-you-configure-desktop-for-a-static-ip-address)

I'm trying to be able to access my `localhost` from any computer on the network. I'm currently doing that by using the `inet addr` under `ifconfig`. But, everytime I restart the computer, it changes. How do I make it static to something like `192.168.1.100`?

I've tried Wicd, but when I use Static IPs, it won't let me connect to the Internet at all.

(Sorry for my naiveness with networking)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do that in Network Manager. Click the network icon and select edit connections. Select your interface and click edit. In the IPv4-settings page, select Method: Manual. Enter your IP address, netmask and gateway and then add one or more DNS servers. If you want the connection to be setup at boot, before you login, select "Available to all users" in the bottom of the screen and click Save. You'll need to be a sudoer in order to do that.

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot access the internet once I do that.